# How can I make a mailing public after it's been sent?

Tags: civimail

If a mailing has already been sent, how can we make the archive of it public? We didn't set the Visibility to Public when we were sending it. Is there a way to change this retroactively?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you can access the civicrm_mailing table you could try changing the value in the column = Visibility so it is set to Public Pages, not User and User Admin Only

Comment: I had to do this quite a lot ("Omg, our subscribers can't open the links or view the online version. Please help (again), Super Admin!"). A good fix which should be possible via CiviCRM Interface.

Comment: Agree that would be a useful contribution to the code for someone to make.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is copy and paste the HTML (under the Source button) of the mailing and paste it into one of your website pages (make sure it can accept Full HTML; that it has no text filtering that may strip some of your elements) - and publish it!