# How to change mailing visibility after sending civimail

Tags: civimail

My org sent a sensitive civimail to selected constituents and is distressed to realize that they left the visibility setting on "public" as they normally do. How do we change the visibility setting after sending so that the public page is taken down? There is an old thread on a similar question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12733/how-can-i-make-a-mailing-public-after-its-been-sent), but I'm hoping there is a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might prefer to use API Explorer rather than SQL.

Using APIv4 Explorer - fill in the ID of your mailing, set the new value of 'visibility' using the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the DB there is a visibility field in the civicrm_mailing table. Looks like it needs the string rather than a 0/1

[image]